# Fix Black Border in Python Batch Raster Conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I have a Raster image like this
[image]

as you can see the road are not connected between 2 raster (up and down) its because the scanned raster use different projection (dgn utm 50s) than my data frame (utm 50s) when I'm doing Georeferencing. Somebody in here (Michael Mils) help me with some python code to create batch raster convertion without change raster name (I modified it a little to match the original raster projection "dgn utm 50 s").
Code :
**Code are Fixed by Michael Mills, Problem Solved, Here's the Complete Code**

```
import arcpy, sys, os

InFolder = r"d:\00_Start"
OutFolder = r"d:\01_End"
OutSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(23880) # "DGN_1995_UTM_Zone_50S"

arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

for Ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
    Name,Ext = os.path.splitext(Ras)
    OutRas = Name + ".tif"
    arcpy.AddMessage("Sementara Proses " + Ras + " Coy")
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (InFolder + "\\" + Ras , OutFolder + "\\" + OutRas,OutSR)
    arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(OutFolder + "\\" + OutRas,"GENERIC","", "", "3 0;2 0;1 0")
    arcpy.AddMessage("So Klar")
```

and the result is like this :
[image]

as you can see the road are connected now and everything's are perfect in place but there are still anoying black border in each raster (all the raster I converted result black border, there are 170 raster I need to process). How to convert using that python script without getting that black border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you project a raster it gets a fine rotation which has to be filled with something, usually 0. After projecting use [SetRasterProperites](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015z000000) in your script to set the null value for the raster.

After setting the nodata value it might be a good idea to build the pyramids and recalculate statistics, but first check to see whether the tool does it automatically; most tools that affect rasters will rebuild the pyramids and statistics dependant on [arcpy.env.rasterStatistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000001z000000) and [arcpy.env.pyramid](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Pyramid/001w0000001w000000/) settings.

Like this, don't forget to `import os`:

```
for Ras in arcpy.ListRasters():
    Name,Ext = os.path.splitext(Ras)
    OutRas = Name + ".tif"
    arcpy.AddMessage("Sementara Proses " + Ras + " Coy")
    arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (InFolder + "\\" + Ras , OutFolder + "\\" + OutRas,OutSR)
    arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(OutFolder + "\\" + OutRas,"GENERIC","", "", "3 0;2 0;1 0")
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the code above, how to apply those setrasterproperties on python?

Comment: Follow the link, there are examples there. Optional parameters use "#", for the NoData value there is no example but from the documentation it should be [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]

Comment: Updated python code in question, but how do i define the statistic? is it already correct? is it okay if i just want to add NoData Value without other atribut setting?

Comment: Statistics can be viewed by looking at the properties in ArcCatalog, on the bottom most of the form. Statistics should only need to be updated if you're actually using them - classifed and stretched renderers. If you are using stretch = none then there's no point having them.

Comment: I use minimum - maximum for stretch. Actualy i just want to remove the blackborder and set every other setting in default. Is okay just set only nodata value attribute?

Comment: Try that first, if you encounter problems you can build pyramids on batch and the same with statistics.

Comment: I have this Line in python : arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management("", "ELEVATION","", "#", "#") 
and it return in ERROR 00735 Input Raster: Value is required
Failed to execute (SetRasterProperties)
any solution?

Comment: see edit. you need to set it for each projected raster.

Comment: There's an error in program : unexpected indent
I have that error message box appear with highlight in arcpy.addmessage

Comment: That error message is possibly because of cut and paste. Your indenting is inconsistent, find the line that is out and re-indent it. Note: I use tabs to indent, if you are using spaces for indent it will confuse the interpreter.

Comment: oh yes (oh gosh this python is too sensitive, I'm sorry my bad habit on php) Indent are solved, now it error invalid syntax with highlighted "arcpy" in arcpy.AddMessage("So Klar")

Comment: Look again at your indenting. There is nothing wrong with the syntax that leaves indenting. The import should be un indented, everything else should be in line until the indent for the for Ras in .. then back to in line.

Comment: edited question, still got same error, I use tab for indent. but still getting invalid syntax...

Comment: already input closed bracket, but still syntax error...

Comment: close off the parenthesis on the line before. arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(InFolder + "\\" + Ras,"GENERIC","#","#","[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]")

Comment: It get this error :
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Network Shared Jica 3\batch raster pc.py", line 12, in <module>
    arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(InFolder + "\\" + Ras,"GENERIC","#","#","[[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]]")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 14062, in SetRasterProperties
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
'

Comment: That's an internal error. I think the syntax is wrong. When I exported a model to python I got arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(Raster, "", "", "", "1 0;2 0;3 0") which is different to the documentation. Try that.

Comment: arcpy.SetRasterProperties_management(InFolder + "\\" + Ras,"GENERIC","#","#","1 0;2 0;3 0")
I tried that no error in script but that annoying black border are stil shown...

Comment: Did you rebuild the pyramid?

Comment: yes, rebuild the pyramid and statistic but it still the same.

Comment: Has that been applied to the raster? Check the properties in ArcCatalog and verify that the null value has been set.

Comment: I check the jpeg file and it shows black border, I guess even I build the pyramid and statistic raster will always show black border. I check properties in arc catalog NoDataValue = 256,256,256

Comment: JPEG does not truly support NoData due to wavelet compression, try TIFF with LZW compression or ERDAS Imagine (no compression) instead.

Comment: any sugestion to modify the python so the resulted convertion are save in outFolder but in tiff format?

Comment: See edits, the tool probably isn't working because it's affecting the *in* raster and not the *out* raster **OOPS!** sorry about that.

Comment: change to output folder but still there are annoying black box. test your update code give error code : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Network Shared Jica 3\batch raster pc.py", line 10, in <module>
    Name,Ext = os.path.splitext(Ras)
NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Comment: you need to import it. *Like this, don't forget to import os:* where you *import arcpy, sys* change it to *import arcpy, sys, os*

Comment: You know what, you are awesome man.. actually I don't understand about python just manage to learn some so I don't quite understand about some function (I think that import similar to PHP include function) anyway thank you so much **IT WORKS!!!** Problem Solved!!